# Sort array with Icelandic locale

Tags: php, locale

I have a list of Icelandic names that I need to sort, e.g.

```
["Árni", "Anna", "Birkir"]
```

The correct icelandic order would have `Á` between `A` and `B`.

If I try to sort via Collator, I get an error message that the fallback was used (= Icelandic is not installed? [How] can I install additional languages for that?)

If I however try to sort via `strnatcmp` after `setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'is_IS')`, it returns Á between Y and Þ (which is wrong).

How can I get correctly sorted Icelandic names without programming it myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Collator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php) class (if available).

```
$arr = ["Árni", "Anna", "Birkir"];
$collator = new Collator('is_IS');
$collator->sort($arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "Anna" [1]=> string(5) "Árni" [2]=> string(6) "Birkir" }
```

With `var_dump(class_exists('Collator', false));` you can check if the class is available.